# xorg: emulate mouse, no numeric keypad

Tags: xorg, input, accessibility, mouseless

How to emulate the mouse without a real mouse on X?

i know about `shift+num lock` but i'm using a half keyboard that does not have a num pad or even the num lock key...

i'm looking for something native that i can just turn on or maybe quickly add to xorg.conf. For now i will do the complex solution (install `xdo` and assign a bunch of hotkeys to invoke xdo scripts to move cursor and click) but i'd love to know the simple way to do that.

PS: if anyone from stackexchange see this: it's very hard to login using the keyboard only as the openid thing you guys use does not have a visible focus nor screen reader hints.

Comment: i'm wondering too.. i'd like to have the arrow (or whatever defined) keys moving cursor pointer temporarily when a special key combination is being pressed down..